# Last item of array enters even by using foreach laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a project in Laravel 5.7, so I have a field in which user can select multiple values in a field (I have used **select2 plugin** for that), if I `dd($request->veryeasy)` it results in an array containing all values selected in the form field, but when I insert the array into database using foreach loop, the last value saves only in the db, my code:

```
//dd($request->veryeasy);
$diffi_lvl_sbj_type = new DiffiLvlSbjType;
foreach ($request->veryeasy as $veryeasy) {
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->sbj_type_id = $veryeasy;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->difficulty_level_id = 1;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->subject_id = $request->subject_id;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created “$diffi_lvl_sbj_type” outside of the foreach loop. But you want to store multiple records. For multiple records, we need to have multiple “diffi_lvl_sbj_type” variables.

How about this one ?

```
foreach ($request->veryeasy as $veryeasy) {
   $diffi_lvl_sbj_type = new DiffiLvlSbjType;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->sbj_type_id = $veryeasy;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->difficulty_level_id = 1;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->subject_id = $request->subject_id;
    $diffi_lvl_sbj_type->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it's working can you tell me the reason, why it was not working outside the foreach?

Comment: You created “$diffi_lvl_sbj_type” outside of the foreach loop. But you want to store multiple records. For multiple records, we need to have multiple “diffi_lvl_sbj_type” variables.